# Fill down a range of rows in R

Tags: r, row, fill, panel-data

I have a panel dataset in R, which includes observations per group over time (month). The following dataframe is a snapshot of the complete dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),month = c("January", "January", "January", "February", "February", "February", "March", "March", "March", "January", "January", "February", "February", "March", "March"),first_value = c("A","BC","D", NA,NA,NA, "D","G","H", "K","L", NA,NA, "DE","GH"),second_value = c(1,5,7, NA,NA,NA, 2,3,9, 7,1, NA,NA, 4,4))
```

The dataset is already arranged by group and time.
As you can see, observations ("first_value*"* and *"*second_value") can be completely empty for a group in a given month (here February, but can be any month except the first and the last month for every group). What I want to achieve is that the empty months are filled with the last non-empty previous month within a group.

I want to get the following dataframe:

```
df_filled <- data.frame(group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),month = c("January", "January", "January", "February", "February", "February", "March", "March", "March", "January", "January", "February", "February", "March", "March"),first_value = c("A","BC","D", "A","BC","D", "D","G","H", "K","L", "K","L", "DE","GH"),second_value = c(1,5,7, 1,5,7, 2,3,9, 7,1, 7,1, 4,4))
```

Please note that, by construction, the last non-empty previous month always has the same number of observations than the following empty months.

I tried different commands with fill() from the dplyr package and na.locf () from the zoo package but all I achieved was filling down the last row of the last non-empty previous month, so that

```
df_filled <- data.frame(group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), month = c("January", "January", "January", "February", "February", "February", "March", "March", "March", "January", "January", "February", "February", "March", "March"), first_value = c("A","BC","D", "D","D","D", "D","G","H", "K","L", "L","L", "DE","GH"), second_value = c(1,5,7, 7,7,7, 2,3,9, 7,1, 1,1, 4,4))
```

Looking forward to your suggestions. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach using `row_number`, assuming there are no 2 consecutive month with `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(n_na = sum(is.na(first_value)), .by = c(group, month)) %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with("_value"), ~ 
           if_else(is.na(.x), .x[row_number() - n_na], .x)), .by = group, 
         n_na = NULL)
   group    month first_value second_value
1      1  January           A            1
2      1  January          BC            5
3      1  January           D            7
4      1 February           A            1
5      1 February          BC            5
6      1 February           D            7
7      1    March           D            2
8      1    March           G            3
9      1    March           H            9
10     2  January           K            7
11     2  January           L            1
12     2 February           K            7
13     2 February           L            1
14     2    March          DE            4
15     2    March          GH            4
```

If consecutive `NA` months are possible with this approach it takes a bit of group juggling

```
df %>% 
  mutate(n_na = sum(is.na(first_value)), .by = c(group, month)) %>% 
  mutate(n_lag = lag(n_na, default=0), .by = group) %>% 
  mutate(n_lag = n_na + first(n_lag), 
         n_na = if_else(n_na != 0, n_lag, n_na), 
         n_lag = NULL, .by = c(group, month)) %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with("_value"), ~ 
           if_else(is.na(.x), .x[row_number() - n_na], .x)), .by = group, 
         n_na = NULL)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Maybe I should have been more precise in my description, there are 2 and more consecutive month with only NAs. Moreover, when running your code, I get the following error message: Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `.by = c(group, month)`.
x `.by` must be size 15 or 1, not 30.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: @tobibow Regarding the error it may be you're running dplyr < 1.1.0. Use `%>% group_by(group, month) %>% ... %>% ungroup() %>% ...` in this case, or simply upgrade. 2 or more `NA` months should work with the second code.